# БД в программе для С#, что выбирают, и что выбрать самому

Tags: c#, база-данных

Доброго всем времени суток господа

В многочисленных обучающих видео по С++/С# описывается использование БД таким образом, что ставим web сервер типа denwer, и там в phpmyadmin база mysql, или mssql с установкой sql server от майкрософт, но.. Что используется в реальной жизни - черт его знает. Допустим те же программы которые устанавливаются на комп, тоже используют БД, но из своего каталога.

Допустим есть желание в плане своего обучения написать программу на С#, которая будет использовать БД. Размер БД 10Мб+++, ест-но пользователь будет у себя эту программу устанавливать без всяких серверов

1. Как организовывается БД в программе? Какие форматы используются? т.е. в чем хранят данные?
2. Нагуглить можно много, но можно нагуглить неправильно.. есть ли какие то обучающие пособия как использовать БД в С#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте про [sqlite](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/), для начала вам этого хватит. Быстрая, простая, не требует установки(рядом с вашим приложением просто будет лежать одна dll-ка).

Вот [пример работы с sqlite на C#](http://easylab.net.ua/net-c-windows-forms/rabota-s-sqlite-na-c)

Answer (score 7):

Для вашей задачи (**Размер БД 10Мб+++, ест-но пользователь будет у себя эту программу устанавливать без всяких серверов**) подходит [MS SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx). C его помощью можно работать с БД, файл которой просто размещен в папке вашего приложения. То есть без установки SQL-сервера, без прав администратора и прочих неудобных штук. Помимо этого есть возможность работать с БД из Visual Studio и поддержка различных БД-API - ADO.NET, NHibernate, Entity Framework. Для его добавления в проект необходимо выполнить в консоли менеджера пакетов следующую команду:

> Install-Package SqlServerCompact

Впрочем, можно установить и через интерфейс NuGet'a

Разумеется, эта версия ориентирована на работу с небольшим числом одновременных подключений. Если есть необходимость в больших масштабах, то здесь уже следует обращаться к "взрослым" БД. Из таковых можно отметить MS SQL Server и Oracle, поставщики данных для которых идут в .NET по умолчанию. Если есть необходимость работы с MySql, то нужно отдельно устанавливать драйвер.

Задумываться о том, как организована БД, и в каких файлах она хранится, особой необходимости нет, поскольку работа с БД в C# осуществляется через набор классов, берущих на себя все низкоуровневые детали реализации конкретной СУБД. Вам лишь необходимо правильно использовать эти классы, и вовремя освобождать ресурсы. Если же вы станете взаимодействовать с БД через ORM, то все еще больше упростится - отпадет даже необходимость писать SQL-запросы.

И еще:

> В многочисленных обучающих видео по С++/С# описывается ...

а вы учитесь не по говнокурсам (уж извините за прямоту), а по нормальным учебным материалам. По C# (и тем более по С++) есть множество отличных книг, в том числе на русском, а у Microsoft имеется обширнейшая MSDN с информацией и примерами на все случаи жизни. Каким бы заманчивым ни казалось обучение по видеокурсам, это очень сомнительный путь хотя бы в силу того, что в Рунете практически нет достойных видеоматериалов по C#. А вся [та мерзость](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZnbK5hkNbc), которой кишит YouTube в лучшем случае бесполезна, а в худшем - даже вредна

Comment: Для обучения sqlite за-глаза хватит.

Comment: @nolka я где-то утверждал обратное?